# time between check of two variables

Tags: javascript

I'm using some animation using a function, let say, animateDiv(), and to which I'm assigning in an interval:

```
setInterval(function(){
   stopDiv();//first stop animation
   if(something == anotherthing){
      doSomething();// it's just about to finish the animation
   }
//now using animate
animateDiv();//finish animation from first to last position smoothly
},0);
```

If I don't use if condition and use doSomething() method directly, it doesn't hamper the animation i.e. smoothly run the animation.

With guess of my eyes there's 100ms gap between stopDiv() and animateDiv() because of checking for something == anotherthing even after this check return false.

So, how should I manage my code? What time does it take to output the result of check between two variables?

Comment: That's weird, the check should be instant.

Comment: Are `something` and `anotherthing` just variables, or are they terms that have to be calculated? You could try `var areEqual = (something == anotherthing); stopDiv(); if (areEqual) { doSomething(); animateDiv(); }`. (I'm assuming it's OK for `animateDiv();` to be inside the `if` block.)

Comment: @DavidKnipe They are variables but in some condition the values are changing...and would it be faster than me what you're showing...?

Comment: If they're just variables then I have no idea why it takes so long.